# How to get the intervals for ntile()

Tags: r, dplyr, percentile

I was trying to figure out if there is a way to get the intervals used for when `ntile()` is used.

I have a sample that I want to use as a basis for getting the percentile values of a larger sample, and I was hoping to find a way to get the value of the intervals for when I use `ntile()`.

Any enlightenment on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really want to put this as a comment, but I stil can't comment.

How about using quantile to generate the interval, like this:

```
# create fake data; 100 samples randomly picked from 1 to 500
fakeData <- runif(100, 1, 500)

# create percentile values; tweak the probs to specify the quantile that you want
x <- quantile(fakeData, probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 100))
```

Then you can apply that interval to the larger data set (i.e., using cut, which might give the same result to the ntile of dplyr).